# Prevent a particular user from cloning my public Github repo

Tags: git, github

How can I avoid a particular user from cloning my repository(public) in Github?

Is there any way to block a specific user?

If I block a user as per GitHub help [here](https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user/)! the user cannot fork and is blocked from some other action. But the blocked user still able to clone the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: you can't stop them from cloning a public repository, as Github allows anonymous read access to public git repositories.([Man page for git http-backend](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html))

Even if you make your repository private, the blocked user could clone someone else's public fork of your repository.